Use list of tuples as parameter in Quarkus Panache named query
I have the following (working) SQL query (names are changed for better readabilty):
select B.a, A.a, A.b
from A
inner join Bb ON A.b_id = B.id
where (A.b_id, A.c_id) in ((13, 113),
                                                      (13, 115),
                                                      (13, 116),
                                                      (13, 117),
                                                      (13, 119),
                                                      (13, 120),
                                                      (13, 121)
--                                                    ...
)
ORDER BY B.a;

Now I want to transform this query into a named panache query like this:
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "A.getEntities",
                query = "select B.a, A.a, A.b from A " +
                        "inner join B ON A.b_id.id = B.id " +
                        "where (A.b_id.id, A.c_id.id) in :keytuples " +
                        "order by B.a"
        )
})
public class Validity extends PanacheEntity {
   // ...

   // ProjectedObject = record class that fits the query result.
   // Pair is just a container for tuples from the package org.javatuples:javatuples:1.2
    public static List<ProjectedObject> getEntities(List<Pair<Long,Long>> keyTuples) {
        return find(
                "#A.getEntities",
                Parameters
                        .with("keytuples", keyTuples)
        ).project(ProjectedObject.class).list();
    }
}

The Problem I now face is that it seems that hibernate/jdbc cannot unpack the list of tuples into the SQL syntax I desire. How can I archive the inital query with a named query or is this not possible?
Stacktrace:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.ArrayTupleType.forEachJdbcType(ArrayTupleType.java:120)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.Bindable.forEachJdbcType(Bindable.java:38)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.resolveSqmParameter(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:6107)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.consumeSqmParameter(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:5677)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.consumeSingleSqmParameter(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:5766)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.processInSingleParameter(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:7932)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.processInSingleHqlParameter(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:7889)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.processInListWithSingleParameter(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:7878)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitInListPredicate(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:7799)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitInListPredicate(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:440)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmInListPredicate.accept(SqmInListPredicate.java:147)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitWhereClause(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2484)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQuerySpec(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2061)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQuerySpec(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:440)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmQuerySpec.accept(SqmQuerySpec.java:127)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.spi.BaseSemanticQueryWalker.visitQueryPart(BaseSemanticQueryWalker.java:218)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQueryPart(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1915)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectStatement(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1600)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectStatement(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:440)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmSelectStatement.accept(SqmSelectStatement.java:228)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.translate(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:776)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.buildCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:402)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:327)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:303)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:509)
at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:427)
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:120)
at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.CommonPanacheQueryImpl.list(CommonPanacheQueryImpl.java:280)
at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.runtime.PanacheQueryImpl.list(PanacheQueryImpl.java:149)
at ai.comp.MyProject.model.A.getBsWithTimeSlotToSegmentAndBIds(A.java:140)
at ai.comp.MyProject.service.SegmentService.getCompleteSegmentById2(SegmentService.java:68
 ai.comp.MyProject.service.SegmentService_ClientProxy.getCompleteSegmentById2(Unknown Source)
 at ai.comp.MyProject.controller.rest.SegmentController.getSegmentById2(SegmentController.java:91)
 at ai.comp.MyProject.controller.rest.SegmentController_Subclass.getSegmentById2$$superforward(Unknown Source)
 at ai.comp.MyProject.controller.rest.SegmentController_Subclass$$function$$25.apply(Unknown Source)
 at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:73)
 at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext$NextAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:97)
 at io.quarkus.security.runtime.interceptor.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:27)
at io.quarkus.security.runtime.interceptor.AuthenticatedInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticatedInterceptor.java:29)
at io.quarkus.security.runtime.interceptor.AuthenticatedInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:70)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext$NextAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:97)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:136)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:107)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:38)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:61)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:32)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:70)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:62)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.StandardSecurityCheckInterceptor.intercept(StandardSecurityCheckInterceptor.java:44)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.StandardSecurityCheckInterceptor_AuthenticatedInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)
at ai.comp.MyProject.controller.rest.SegmentController_Subclass.getSegmentById2(Unknown Source)
at ai.comp.MyProject.controller.rest.SegmentController_ClientProxy.getSegmentById2(Unknown Source)
at ai.comp.MyProject.controller.rest.SegmentController$quarkusrestinvoker$getSegmentById2_4b732ff4c8c7f72a964cdb1a2e32dd218a3fa90d.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:582)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

